# Symfony2 - Setting up service error with undefined getDoctrine()

Tags: php, symfony, search, service, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to setup a search function as a service. My code is below and am getting the following error when submitting the search word:

FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\ProjectBundle\Services\Search::getDoctrine() in /var/www/html/Project/src/Acme/ProjectBundle/Services/Search.php line 24

Do I need to inject doctrine somehow?

**config.yml**

```
services:
    search:
    class: Acme\ProjectBundle\Services\Search
    arguments: ["@request_stack"]
    scope: request
```

**IndexAction Controller**

```
$query = $this->get('search');
$results = $query->search();
return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Default:index.html.twig, array(
    'query'  => $query,
    'results => $results,
));
```

**Search service**

```
class Search
{
private $request;

public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
}

public function search()
{
    $results = null;
    $query = $this->request->query->get('q');

    if (!empty($query)) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        $results = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('AcmeProjectBundle:Blog', 'b')
            ->select('b')
            ->where('b.title LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter(':search', "%${query}%")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
//        exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($em));
    return array(
        'query'   => $query,
        'results' => $results,
    );
}
}
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{% block search %}
<form action="{{ path('acme_project_search') }}" method="GET">
    <label><input type="search" name="q" value={{ app.request.query.get('q') }}></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<br>
{% endblock %}

{% for result in query %}

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
            <div class="blog-post">

                <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ result.title }}</h2>
                <p class="blog-post-meta"><time datetime="{{ result.created|date('c') }}">{{ result.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}</time> by <a href="#">{{ result.author }}</a></p>

                <p>{{ result.blog|truncate(350, true) }}</p><br>

                <div class="tags">
                    <p><strong>Tags: </strong><span class="highlight">{{ result.tags }}</span></p>
                </div>

            </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: arguments: ["@request_stack",@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]and class search __construct add a $em parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to inject doctrine 'manually'. Your service definition should look like:

```
services:
    search:
        class: Acme\ProjectBundle\Services\Search
        arguments: ["@request_stack", @doctrine]
        scope: request
```

And your constructor should look like:

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, Registry $doctrine)
{
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}
```

and then you can use it in your `search` method:

```
public function search()
{
    (...)
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager()
}
```

NOTE: `$this->getDoctrine()` method you're trying to use is a method of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` class, and you're probably get used to using it from your controllers, but your own service you need to inject `doctrine` as a dependency

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. That took care of the error but am now running into (Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a string variable ("practice") in AcmeProjectBundle:Default:search.html.twig at line 31) -- "practice" is a search word for one of the titles I'm looking for. Does my query need to be changed in the search class?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more code. You don't need `:` sign in your setParameter call, maybe this is the case.

Comment: This is continuation question from my original that's still unresolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796723/symfony2-how-to-implement-this-search-function-as-a-service

Comment: By : do you mean to not use ->setParameter('`:`search', "%${query}%") ?

Comment: Yes, you can do ->setParameter('search', "%${query}%") but this is rather blind shot

Comment: And for `->where('b.title LIKE :search')` do I keep the `:`?

Comment: yes, you do (some additional characters to match minimal comment lenght)

Comment: I tried that (removed the : on parameter) and I changed the code in the twig file to use query instead of results for the for loop (for result in query), the 'impossible' error is now gone but the query turns up nothing. Seems my query code is broke when trying to make it into a re-usable service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the container inject an `EntityManager` into your service.

```
services:
    search:
    class: Acme\ProjectBundle\Services\Search
    arguments: ["@request_stack","@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    scope: request
```