# Getting Route object from GetResponseEvent

Tags: symfony, routes

I am implementing a `RequestListener` class per the instructions at [How to register a new Request Format and Mime Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/request/mime_type.html).

I would like to access the metadata from the routes.yml file (I believe I need a `Symfony\Component\Routing\Route` object) for the current request so that I can see what formats the current route permits.

How can I obtain this object? Doing `var_dump($event); die;` resulted in a 600+ MB response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to make RequestListener a subclass of ContainerAware (or implement ContainerAwareInterface). See @bigmax's answer at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126835/760706