# Symfony2 phpUnit YAML parse error

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, yaml

I'm trying to run unit test in symfony2 project, but tests fails because of YAML parse error:

```
The file "../services.yml" does not contain valid YAML in "../"
```

Caused by:

```
The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar at line 6 (near "- [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]").
```

For sure, I should use quotes, but that's work on other PC, so what should I do to solve this error, but not using quotes?

Comment: It's because your other pc is using an older version of the software.  Just quote your @ strings and move on.

Comment: so not quoting spec. characters is OLD syntax and I should force all my colleagues to use quotes?

Comment: Yep and yep.  Put coal in their stockings if they refuse.  You can check the change documents.  Turns out that unquoted @ symbols were never legal yaml anyways.  And quoting them won't hurt your old code.

Comment: ofc, I checked all spec on official website, it's illegal, but it worked. So I thought that I'm using old version of yaml parser or something like that.. Or doing all wrong. Thanks!