# How to get the root path in Helper Class - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

My code of Helper Class is as below :

```
public function getPlaceholders()
{
    try {
        echo $this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
    } catch (ParseException $e) {
        printf("Unable to parse the YAML string: %s", $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->placeholders;
}
```

It's returning the error as below :

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParameter" of class "AppBundle\Helper\Placeholders".
```

Please advice me on it.

Comment: The error means that doesn't exists a `getParameter` method on the `Placeholders` class.

Comment: So how can use getParameter in my Helper Class? @Federkun

Comment: `getParameter` is a container's method, just inject it in `Placeholders` and use it. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126277/how-to-give-container-as-argument-to-services )

Comment: Can you tell me how?
Because I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the container

```
services:
    app.helper.placeholders:
        class: AppBundle\Helper\Placeholders
        arguments: ['@service_container']
```

And use the container's accessor methods for parameters:

```
namespace AppBundle\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class Placeholders
{    
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getPlaceholders()
    {
        $root_dir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');

        // ...
```

Comment: It's fine but I have to call this is in controller so I have write like as  : $placeholders = new Placeholders();
So what I have to pass argument in new Placeholders(); method because __construct has one argument.

Comment: I am not omniscient, you know: `new Placeholders($this->container)`