# Get request service from a DataTransformer class

Tags: php, symfony

Short story:
I need to get the Request service from a class that doesn't inherit from the Controller class (it's a DataTransformer which -obviously- implements the DataTransformerInterface).

Long story:
I have an embedded form that has an email field. If the user enters an email which doesn't exists in my users database table, I want to create a new user with this email.
In order to do that, I need to set its IP, so I followed the [embedded forms tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms) and the [data transformer recipe](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), but finally I have no idea where I'm able to inject the Request instance to my DataTransformer constructor or something else.

If I was in a class extending form the Controller one, it would be as simple as:
`$this->container->get('request')->getClientIp()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by ["Referencing (Injecting) Services"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services). In your case you want to inject the Request which is a [service from a narrower scope](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#using-a-service-from-a-narrower-scope).

If you are using transformers, you are probably already using a Custom Form Type, and are instantiating the Data Transformer within your Form Type **BuildForm** Method, see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-the-transformer) for more info.

You want to inject the Request object to the custom Form Type, then it can passed to the Data Transformer as a constructor parameter.

To do this modify the `services.yml` file with in your bundle, and add a constructor to the Custom Form Type and the Custom Data Transformer like this:

```
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    // ...    

services:
    acme.type.custom_type:
        class: Acme\HelloBundle\Form\Type\CustomType
        scope: request
        arguments: ["@doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager", "@request"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: custom_type }
```

The update the CustomType Class like this:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Form/Type/CustomType.php

namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;

use Acme\HelloBundle\Form\DataTransformer\CustomDataTransformer;

class CustomType extends AbstractType
{
    private $request;
    private $dm;

    public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm, Request $request) {
        $this->dm = $dm;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Create a new Data Transformer that will be able to use the Request Object!
        $transformer = new CustomDataTransformer($this->dm, $this->request);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }
    // ...
}
```

and finally add a constructor to the transformer similar to the one added in the Form Type:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Form/DataTransformer/CustomDataTransformer.php

namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;

class CustomDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $request;
    private $dm;

    public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm, Request $request) {
        $this->dm = $dm;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice that along with the Request I have injected the MongoDB DocumentManager, this is to show that multiple objects can be injected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll do it like you're suggesting instead of using the method described in my own answer.

I only have 1 question about it:  
Is it better to inject the Request object and set the service scope to request than inject the Container object and then get the request service?

Comment: Symfony2 provides the Service Container as a way to manage the instantiation of services (objects), that way you don't have to re-write your code if you where to re-use your Custom Form Type elsewhere. Also note that you could inject the DI container to your Custom Form Type using this method see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056178/how-to-access-service-container-in-symfony2-global-helper-function-service. But try not to rely on having the DI container as it will make your code less reusable, see http://bit.ly/PKqPj7.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's simple:
In my question I was assuming that the DataTransformer will be "magically" invoked, but it's instanced while building the form, so if it helps to anyone, here it is:

1. In the DataTransformer class (implementing the DataTransformerInterface):

   1. Define the new class attributes in order to hold the dependency injection:

      ```
      /**
       * @var EntityManager
       */
       private $entityManager;

      /**
      * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container
      */
      private $container;
      ```
   2. Define the constructor like:

      ```
      public function __construct( EntityManager $entityManager, Container $container )
      {
          $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
          $this->container = $container;
      }
      ```
2. In your form class (implementing the AbstractType)

   1. Add the following calls to the *setDefaultOptions* method:

      ```
      $resolver->setRequired( array( 'em', 'container' ) );

      $resolver->setAllowedTypes( array(
                                   'em'        => 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager',
                                   'container' => 'appDevDebugProjectContainer',
                              ) );
      ```
   2. In the *buildForm* method, apply the transformer as defined in the [transformer recipe](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) but instance it as:

      ```
      $entityManager = $options['em'];
      $container     = $options['container'];
      $transformer = new FantasticTransformer( $entityManager, $container );
      ```
3. In your controller, when you're calling to the *createForm* method, is it possible to inject the EntityManager and the Container instances simply adding them as follows:

   ```
       $form = $this->createForm( 'your_form', $lookup, array(
                                                               'action' => $this->generateUrl( 'your_action_url' ),
                                                               'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
                                                               'container' => $this->container
                                                          ) );
   ```
4. Now, you can finally get the client IP from the request service calling to the container defined in the constructor of your DataTransformer class:

   ```
   $ip = $this->container->get('request')->getClientIp();
   ```

Note that we're injecting the container instead of the request instance, it's due to the [Symfony scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html).