# Use locate to set default choice in Symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm building a newsletter subscription form in Symfony2. In this form these is a field where users can select there language. In this example I set it default to NL. But how can I get the active (user selected locate on the platform) locate value and use it here?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('langId', 'choice', array(
            'translation_domain' => 'messages',
            'choices' => array(
                'NL' => 'dutch',
                'EN' => 'english',
                'DE' => 'german',
            ),
            'data' => 'NL'
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

Comment: @See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073425/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-list-of-available-locales-in-php

Comment: I don't mean the available location but the one that for the user is active on the Symfony2 platform.

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949397/how-to-get-the-current-locale-in-symfony-2-3

Comment: That works fine in a controller, but this is in the formtype definition. Here is the request and $this not available?

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878368/get-request-service-from-a-datatransformer-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller get the locale in a variable.
After when creating the form pass as parameter the locale :

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourType::class, $yourEntity, ['locale' => $locale]);
```

In your form add in your default options the 'locale' key with null default value :

```
//from Symfony v2.7
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'locale' => null
    ));
}

//or this for older versions 

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'locale' => null
    );
}
```

And finally use it to define your default value of your ChoiceType :

```
'data' => $options['locale'],
```

Hope this will help you.