# Symfony access parameters.yml from vendor folder

Tags: php, symfony

I got my some custom classes in my vendor folder which I use in my Symfony project. Now I need to access some parameters from my parameters.yml which is located in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\config\parameters.yml
```

In my regular Symfony code I just do

```
$this->getParameter('myparameter');
```

and all set, but not in vendor folder. I guess I need to import some namespaces, but could not find which? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPD1** The issue was solved by adding the following code to AppBundle.php

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
private static $containerInstance = null;

public function setContainer(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    parent::setContainer($container);
    self::$containerInstance = $container;
}

public static function getContainer()
{
    return self::$containerInstance;
}
}
```

and then calling the container from my vendor code with the following:

```
use AppBundle\AppBundle;
AppBundle::getContainer()->getParameter('myparameter');
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: [Inject the service container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056178/how-to-access-service-container-in-symfony2-global-helper-function-service) and use [`->getParamter()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html)?

Comment: Do I need to define it as a service, or using use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container; is enough? Btw, this approach does not work saying Undefined property $container

Comment: @Jack Your updated code is exactly what **not** to do. Statically getting parameters from the container is defeating the whole purpose of the container. Your classes in the vendor folder will now be tightly coupled to the AppBundle class and the container. Please do not do this. Inject the required parameters into the class through its constructor when it's instantiated. That's what the dependency injection container is for. My answer below explains.

Answer (score 0):

> DependencyInjection/YourBundleExtension.php

```
$container->setParameter('myparameter', $config);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/dependency_injection.html#main

After that, add this config to your service (for example)

> Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
your.service:
    class: App\YourBundle\Service\YourService
    arguments:
        - %myparameter%
```

Comment: yes, but how can I access it from my class which is located in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\myotherclass\myotherclass.php? It knows nothing about Symfony container.

Comment: If you'll use Injection it will know about containers. I think there is no other ways ... you can parse yml file from your class, but this is incorrect using of Symfony

Comment: any examples how injection could be used here are welcome. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy

Comment: You can check my bundle for example: https://github.com/wow-apps/symfony-slack-bot how to use configs and how to create public bundle that will be downloadable from composer

Answer (score 0):

You can either define your services in

1. `C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\config\services.yml`
2. The `Resources\config` directory of a bundle. See [How to Load Service Configuration inside a Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html).

---

You simply define your services by giving them a name, specifying the class and then listing any arguments the class has to be injected into it when it is instantiated. To reference a parameter from **parameters.yml** you wrap the name of the parameter in `%%` as I did below.

```
services:
   my_project.some_service:
      class: Vendor\Class\Name\Here
      arguments: ['%some.parameter.name%']
```

In 99% of scenarios you definitely should **not** inject the dependency injection container into your own classes. Having your classes depend on the container is not good - have them depend on other services from your project or simple values such as strings, integers etc.