# Symfony how to get container in my service

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, facade

I have [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) project and inside this project, I have big own service which is huge and complicated with own dependencies etc...
And I wanna create [facade](/questions/tagged/facade) for this service with purpose to use my service in `controllers` like:

```
$myService = $this->container->get('service_from_my_domain');
```

My question - is how inside my facade I can get access to `container` to service's dependencies. I know only 1 way - is to inject dependency into service in yaml config.

But is there another way to do it? Like:

```
$dependency = Container::getInstance()->get('my_dependency_service');
```

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797432/3612353) but using global variable feels like back in time...

PS: I don't want to inject dependency through yaml config (not constructor injection nor setter injection) because I don't need IoC ([inversion-of-control](/questions/tagged/inversion-of-control)) here.

Comment: I've found lot of question with the same name, but this one about another problem, hence please pay attention before mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't understand why do you even need the container if you don't want to use IoC and DI ?

Comment: Container::getInstance() is using a global.  In fact, if you want to globally access the container then you pretty much need to use a global by definition.  Call it a facade like Laravel does if it makes you feel better but it is still a global.

Comment: @RamyNasr I need container because I have to work with other services...

Comment: This is quite not recommended. but you can inject the container in this one god service you want to use by using `'@service_container'` in `service.yml`

Comment: @RamyNasr But I don't want to inject service. Injection means you can pass instance1 or instance2 as far as this instance implement injection interface, but I need use certain class in my service without replacing opportunity.

Comment: @RamyNasr DI is IoC but I need high-level behavior depend on low-level behavior. I don't need fake IoC which is described here https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=inversion-of-control&author=john-sonmez&name=inversion-of-control&clip=4&mode=live

Comment: IoC does NOT necessarily mean that services can be interchangeable. You can easily enforce an specific class or interface when implementing your services `public function __construct(verySpecificServiceToBeInjected $service) {}`. Either I can't understand what you are saying, or your understanding of what IoC and DI is totally different from mine.

Comment: @RamyNasr When you use `verySpecificServiceToBeInjected` you very far from IoC because no inversion is here... Your top-level behavior depends on low-level `verySpecificServiceToBeInjected` behavior...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak isn't this what you said you want to do? Anyway, seems to be a lot of confusion. I will let you figure out what is best for you. Thanks :)

Comment: @RamyNasr Yes, it is exactly what I'm trying to find but without ussing `__construct(verySpecificServiceToBeInjected $service)` without this pseudo IoC...

Comment: The example I gave was not IoC at all. It is just a way of making the dependency visible up front. getting a service that you depend on, in the middle of the code, might mean that your dependency is buried deep and other developers might not see it right away.

Answer (score 8):

can you do like this

```
services:
     kernel.listener.acme_listener:
          class: Acme\AcmeBundle\EventListener\AcmeListener
          arguments:
                - @service_container
          tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

your Listener

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class AcmeListener
 {
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
     private $container;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Container $container
     */
   public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

   public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $this->container->...
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to inject dependency through yaml config.

Comment: Add service.yml

Comment: I don't need DI. I need to get container in my service without DI.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to have a fun and do code escapades, you could do something like this...

Create a `Facade` class, that must be initialized when the app starts. So, in `app.php`, just after the line `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` do the `Facade` initialization:

```
$kernel->boot();
$container = $kernel->getContainer();
\MyBundle\Facade::init($container);
```

And, here is a code for the `Facade` class:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle;


use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class Facade
{
    /**
     * self|null
     */
    private static $instance = null;

    /**
     * ContainerInterface
     */
    private static $myContainer;

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    private function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        self::$myContainer = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $serviceId
     *
     * @return object
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public static function create($serviceId)
    {
        if (null === self::$instance) {
            throw new \Exception("Facade is not instantiated");
        }

        return self::$myContainer->get($serviceId);
    }

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     *
     * @return null|Facade
     */
    public static function init(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        if (null === self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self($container);
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

And, wherever you need some service, you create it this way:

`$service = \MyBundle\Facade::create('my_dependency_service');`

---

But, if you ask me - I would create a Facade service, that would have a container injected in the constructor.
And you would have some method for service creation (`Facade::create($serviceId)`), that would ask the container for given service ID.

Comment: This is the only way i could make the container work with "new Controller()" .. sad :(

Answer (score 4):

I've built a console app using Symfony 5.

Injecting a service in Symfony 5 is as simples as `__construct(ServiceClass $service_name)` ( type-hinting ) and everything is a service. But in one case I could not dependency inject at the constructor because the dependency service is conditioned to the parameters given at the command line.

So this is how I injected the needed service on the fly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use App\Kernel;

class MyCommand extends Command {
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:my-command';
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Kernel $kernel) {
        $this->container = $kernel->getContainer();
        //...
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure() {
        // ...
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        //...
        // read the parameters given in the cmd and decide what class is
        // gona be injected.
        // $service_name = "App\\My\\Namespace\\ServiceClassName"
        $service = $this->container->get($service_name);
        $service->doSomething();

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```